# Como tirar esse pontos

Tags: html

Fiz uma barra de navegação mas no começo de cada "links" tem esse ponto

```
<nav class="bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Phones</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Connected Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lapstops</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tablets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Acessories</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No teu css, adicione:

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Ou utilizando somente o html:

```
<ul style="list-style: none;">
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Muito Obrigado.